# Instead Of Delete trigger code for multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, foreign-keys, sql-delete

Following is an example of tables I have:

```
 Parent: Id  Type
  Row-1  1     a
  Row-2  2     a
  Row-3  3     b

 Child:  Id  Type  Col
  Row-1  1     a   ....
  Row-2  1     b   ....
  Row-3  2     a   ....
```

When I delete a row from the `Parent` table corresponding rows that match `Id & type` must also be deleted from the `Child` table.

Following `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger would work for a single row delete from Parent table but would fail when multiple rows are deleted. Can anyone suggest a working solution.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [InsteadOFDelete] ON [dbo].[Parent] 
    INSTEAD OF DELETE 
AS 

BEGIN

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
        RETURN

    DECLARE @id Int , @type nvarchar(max)
    Select @id = Id,@type = Type  FROM deleted

    DELETE FROM Child WHERE Child.Id = @id AND Child.Type = @type;
    //Then delete from the parent table

END
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using inner join to `deleted` table like this:

```
delete C
from Child as C
    inner join deleted as D on D.ID = C.ID and D.Type = C.Type

delete P
from Parent as P
    inner join deleted as D on D.ID = P.ID and D.Type = P.Type
```

Comment: @ShyamalParikh well, technically this can be done using cursor in the manner similar to one you've used (create cursor, fetch records from deleted one-by-one and delete from child and parent). But it is not recommended way since it is much slower than way I've suggested.